# Prevent iPhone from launching HLS stream in full screen

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, http-live-streaming

Building a web app with an HLS stream as the center piece. When viewing the stream on an iOS with a smaller screen it automatically launches the player in full screen. Is there a way to prevent this?

[From the Apple docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> The Safari browser can play HTTP streams within a webpage on iPad and
>   desktop computers, and Safari launches a full-screen media player for
>   HTTP streams on iOS devices with small screens, such as iPhone and
>   iPod touch.

I was not able to find any details on how to prevent the full screen functionality. It should be possible since it plays the stream within the page on iPad...

The stream is defined in a `<video>` tag like so:

```
<video id="video" muted>
    <source src="{{HLS_URL}}" type="video/mp4" /> 
</video>
```